# django-channels/websockets: WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 200

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am following this tutorial: https://gearheart.io/blog/creating-a-chat-with-django-channels/

And I get this error with the following code while running manage.py runserver

```
#settings.py

redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')

# Channel layer definitions
# http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploying.html#setting-up-a-channel-backend
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        # This example app uses the Redis channel layer implementation asgi_redis
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(redis_host, 6379)],
        },
       "ROUTING": "gameapollius.routing.channel_routing", # We will create it in a moment
    },
}

#routing.py

from channels import route,include

def message_handler(message):
    print(message['text'])

channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.receive', message_handler)
]

#traceback

In [1]: import websocket

In [2]: ws = websocket.WebSocket()

In [3]: ws.connect("ws://localhost:8000")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebSocketBadStatusException               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-43b98f503495> in <module>()
----> 1 ws.connect("ws://localhost:8000")

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.pyc in connect(self, url, **options)
212
213         try:
--> 214             self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
215             self.connected = True
216         except:

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.pyc in handshake(sock, hostname, port, resource, **options)
 67     dump("request header", header_str)
 68
---> 69     status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
 70     success, subproto = _validate(resp, key, options.get("subprotocols"))
 71     if not success:

c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\websocket\_handshake.pyc in _get_resp_headers(sock, success_status)
127     status, resp_headers = read_headers(sock)
128     if status != success_status:
--> 129         raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d", status)
130     return status, resp_headers
131

WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 200
```

What am I doing wrong? I have followed the tutorial to the T up until the "ws.connect("ws://localhost:8000")" line. This is where I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My error was that I forgot to add 'channels' to my installed apps

Comment: ahahahha, I am following the same tutorial and the same error has brought me here :) thanks for answering your own question :)